# Why this javascript function generator is not working?

Tags: javascript, generator

```
const f = n => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if (n > 2){
            resolve({result: `${n} is higher than 2`});
        } else {
            resolve({error: `${n} is lower than 2`});
        }
    }, 1000);
});
function *m(){
    const {result, error} = yield f(parseInt(process.argv[2]));
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
}
m();
```

I'm using node.js v6.2 and when I execute `node file.js 344` there is no result. 
If I put a debugger inside whatever function I choose, it doesn't stop while in debug mode.

It only stops if I extract the iterator with `const it = m();` But I've seen examples where the above pattern seems to be correct. What am I missing? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are the smart quotes intended?

Comment: You yield the promise, but don't do anything with it. Don't you need a corountine environment to achieve this?

Comment: I think a promise should be only returned from a function and only while using the word "return".

Try something like `n() return New Promise((resolve, reject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `m()` you are initialising the generator but not doing anything with it. For the yield to happen you need to call `next()` on the result of `m()`.

i.e

```
let generator = m()
generator.next().value.then(result => console.log(result)) 

// will log { result: '344 is higher than 2' } to the console
```

When you call `next` execution of the generator will resume and it will suspend when it encounters a `yield`. In this case the yield returns a promise, which will be available in the `value` property of the result of `next`.

https://davidwalsh.name/async-generators is a good read on the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer and the link were very helpful